# Запретить скролл вверх

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Существует ли возможность с помощью js/jquery сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог прокручивать страницу вниз, а вверх не мог ? Если можно, то подскажите, а то не знаю даже, как это загуглить

Answer (score 2):

Можно начать с этого:

```
$('body').on({
    'mousewheel': function(e) {  
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY>0){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();}
    }
})
```

Но можно все равно прокручивать страницу с помощью скроллбара. Поэтому пойдет еще вариант:

```
var stmax=0;
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
     var st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop; 
     if(st>stmax){
          stmax=st
     }else{
          $(window).scrollTop(stmax);
     }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Думаю тут стоит поставить слушателя на событие scroll для window, затем смотреть знак дельты прокрученных пикселей. Что-нибудь вроде:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);

var scrollPrev = 0; 
var scrollDelta = 0;

function scrollHandler(e) {
    scrollDelta = e.target.scrollTop - scrollPrev;
    if(scrollDelta < 0){
      e.target.scrollTop = scrollPrev ;
    }
    scrollPrev = e.target.scrollTop;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Рекомендую разверстать Вам страничку без скролл бара вовсе. Подготовить адаптивные блоки на всю ширину-высоту экрана. В низу добавить кнопку вниз. По клике по ней и скроллу вниз скрывать активный блок и отображать следующий.

Примеров анимаций в интернете предостаточно, вот пример кода:

```
var activeBlock = 0;
var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var bo = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (bo > scrollPos)
            // scroll bottom
            $(".block"+activeBlock).addClass('hidden');
            activeBlock++;
            $(".block"+activeBlock).removeClass('hidden');
        } else {
            // scroll top
        }
        scrollPos = bo;
    });
});
```

Comment: а можно просто подписаться на событие скролла и запретить скроллить вверх, без ерунды с левыми блоками без скроллов вовсе. Зачем так странно усложнять?

Comment: Тут уже есть правильные ответы, зачем мне создавать новый?

Comment: Я лишь задал Вам вопрос, а вы вдруг начали огрызаться, не понимаю Вас. Я спросил зачем вы так усложнили свой подход и все.